# (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server

Tags: php, fastcgi, plesk, internal-server-error, mod-fcgid

I am using a Ubuntu 12 Server with Plesk 12 running on it.
 
I get the following-error in irregular distances which ends up with an Internal Server error!
 
When I reload the page it's the same problem but after about a minute the error disapears.

```
[time] [error] [client x.x.x.x] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://host.co/test 
[time] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer
```

I have tried a lot (checking my permissions, changing the FcgidBusyTimeout, …) but it has become even worse (my subjective grading).

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try to increase following setting on your server under fcgid.conf file.

```
FcgidIdleTimeout 3600
FcgidIdleScanInterval 480
FcgidBusyTimeout 1800
FcgidBusyScanInterval 480
FcgidZombieScanInterval 12
FcgidErrorScanInterval 12
```

Comment: Thanks. This does help.

Comment: doc ref for those props https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgididletimeout